# Member/ User portal integrate with Dynamic 365

Tags: craft4

I am looking for a solution to integrate my Dynamic 365 Database with CraftCMS Front-end user.

I have done some digging for how Dynamic 365 can integrate, but seems like it is limited at form (https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/formie/docs/integrations/crm) but not actually logging in into the CraftCMS member portal. I would like let user to store something like favorite post or link to the account but under 365 user database.

Does anyone have any thoughts or plugin to do these?

Answer (score 0):

As you’ve found, the Formie plugin does have an integration with Dynamics 365, but only with forms.

I’m unaware of any other plugin in the [Plugin Store](https://plugins.craftcms.com) that offers this, so you’re likely looking at a [custom integration](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/) in the form of a plugin or module.